# Is still LD_PRELOAD works on android 6.0

Tags: android, system, native

I have tried following a tutorial at [How to wrap a system call (libc function) in Linux](http://samanbarghi.com/blog/2014/09/05/how-to-wrap-a-system-call-libc-function-in-linux/) on Android. It's working on Ubuntu 16.04, but when I tried on Android it's not working.

Here are my steps:

- Push the library to the device.

  ```
  adb push libpreload.so /data/libpreload.so
  ```
- Set system property on Android terminal:

  ```
  setprop com.foo.bar LD_PRELOAD=/data/libpreload.so
  ```

I traced all system calls on an Android device by using strace. I don't get the message:

```
"write(0, "Hello, Kernel!\n", 15Hello, Kernel!)        = 15"
```

Did I miss anything? Does Ld_preload work on Android 6.0?

Answer (score 2):

*Answering this question, as some information is missing which could be beneficial if people find this question.*

Yes, it works on Android 6.
Besides the mistake in your command as mentioned in the answer above, on Android 6 SELinux blocks the shared library. You have to set it to permissive mode in order to get it working. For this you most likely need **root** acces on your phone.

#### Enable:

1. `adb shell`
2. `su`
3. `setenforce 0`
4. verify with `getenforce` it is set to `Permissive`

#### Disable:

1. `adb shell`
2. `su`
3. `setenforce 1`
4. verify with `getenforce` it is set to `Enforcing`

Answer (score 1):

Your `setprop` call is incorrect. You need to set the `wrap` property of the target package:

```
setprop wrap.com.foo.bar LD_PRELOAD=/data/libpreload.so
```

Also make sure the library is readable and executable: `adb shell chmod a+rx /data/libpreload.so`.